# Open data with AB test results

Tags: data-request

I'm teaching an online course on A/B testing, and I'd like some real world data to use in my course.  However, I've had a really hard time finding good examples of A/B testing datasets, as it seems companies like to keep this information private.  Does anyone know of any good resources for this problem?

Comment: Do you find any useful open data now?

Comment: I didn't find anything useful; I ended up using synthetic data for my course.